# How can I persist a class to a single column using NHibernate

Tags: nhibernate, serialization

I'm looking to persist an object to a single column using NHibernate.  I'd like to serialize the data on the way in into a single column, and then deserialize it on the way out.  This could be binary or xml.  How can I go about doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Serialization is the default, if the class is not mapped. You can (should) make it explicit:

```
<property name="MyProperty" type="Serializeable" />
```

Comment: Wow, that worked!  I didn't realize it was that simple!  I was going this roundabout route with a String type and then thinking I had to somehow manage to get someone to serialize it into XML before handing it off to NHibernate... I severely underestimated the framework... THANKS!

Comment: @noah: flag it as an answer please.

Answer (score 0):

Create a property that would implement serialization/deserialization, map that property to the desired column in HBM. Seems simple enough... Where is the trick? :)